# Condition for specific range of time to identify Shift

Tags: php

I have a piece of PHP program that would supposedly identify the Shift time of a user when they login.. see below actual script condition.

```
$dt = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$dt->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone("Asia/Manila") );
$timeNow = $dt->format('H:i:s');

if (strtotime($timeNow) >= mktime(07,0,0) && strtotime($timeNow) < mktime(15,0,0)){
    $shift = "2nd [0700H - 1500H]";
}elseif(strtotime($timeNow) >= mktime(15,0,0) && strtotime($timeNow) < mktime(23,0,0)){
    $shift = "3rd [1500H - 2300H]";
}else{
    $shift = "1st [2300H - 0700H]";
}
```

The script above is working but there are records that falls into wrong shift.. for example a user access the page in **7:10AM which means should be in 2nd Shift** but instead.. **it falls into 1st Shift**

I don't know what have I missed in this control flow.. so if anyone from here can help and share ideas that would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you checked the time in the `$timeNow` variable, bcoz there may be changes in server time.

Comment: What is the actual value of `$timeNow` when it falls into the 1st shift? Is it **literally** `$timeNow === "7:10AM"`?

Comment: Check my code above I have added the initialization of the $timeNow... the script has date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");

Comment: o.0 that is the most bizarre code I have ever seen. Your code literally says, give me the time in `America/Los_Angeles`, convert it to `Asia/Manila`, then convert that to `UTC`. What a circuitous way of just saying `time()`, eh?

Comment: @Sherif ..That's because I have to convert the time from America/Los_Angeles to Asia/Manila.. the whole application is defaulted to America/Los_Angeles...
That's why I'm using DateTime and DateTimeZone for that specific section of the script only..

Comment: @Sherif .. So correct me if I'm wrong.. am I using the strtotime() incorrectly?... when you said converted it again to UTC?.. so I'm guessing strtotime() is using UTC ? is that what you were saying?..

Comment: No, that is not correct. You just don't need timezones here **at all**. Period. Full stop. You're not trying to compare times in different timezones. You're only trying to figure out what time it is in UTC ***right now***. That's it. So there's no need for *any of this*. `time()` gives you a Unix timestamp, which is in UTC. That's all you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between using `DateTime::setTimezone()` and applying a timezone in the `DateTime` constructor. The former, converts the existing time to the `DateTimezone` specified as the argument to `DateTime::setTimezone()`, and the latter, assumes that the supplied formatted date is *already* in that timezone.

You're saying you want to know whether right now it's between 7 am and 3 pm in Manila, or between 3 pm and 11 pm, etc... So the idea is to compare only within that timezone. There is no need to do any timezone conversion here whatsoever.

```
$now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Manila"));

$shift2 = new DateTime("7:00 AM", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Manila"));
$shift3 = new DateTime("3:00 PM", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Manila"));
$shift1 = new DateTime("11:00 PM", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Manila"));

if ($now >= $shift2 && $now < $shift3) {
    // It's shift 2
} elseif ($now >= $shift3 && $now < $shift1) {
    // It's shift 3
} else {
    // It's shift 1
}
```

Comment: If I'll use just time() .. then the script will use UTC.. correct?.. then if user is  from manila how's that compared to UTC?.. for example if user from manila time is 7:10AM then surely it's not the same with UTC time()....

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is to Check if user is logging in based on the schedule which is 1st,2nd & 3rd shift identified above.. in Manila Time...

Comment: OK, so you're saying you want to apply this logic based on the user's timezone, not based on UTC? Because your code indicated otherwise.

Comment: Yes that's correct... the User's Timezone.. that's the reason why I'm converting it to Asia/Manila timezone... and I don't want to change the default timezone because it would mess other script using the default timezone...

Comment: So what I really want is that.. first Convert the time to Manila Time from the default timezone to user's timezone then check if the time falls to user's shift in manila time.

Comment: No, what you really want is to compare two `DateTime` objects in the same timezone. You don't actually want to **convert** anything.

Comment: That's it... my bad.. Thank You very much @Sherif ;-)